# Update WordPress - Another update is currently in progress

Tags: updates

**Update WordPress**

> Another update is currently in progress.

This message is displayed for a month already

I don't have any `.maintenance` files at my www's fodlers, subfolders

I don't have any `core_updater` or `core_updater.lock` in my database

(so I ask you to not mention about this)

Any normal solution?

> WordPress 4.9.7 running
>
> WordPress 4.9.8 is available! Please update now.